# Hazelcast Hibernate CacheKey size

Tags: java, hibernate, hazelcast

We are currently creating a cluster using Hazelcast across three nodes with Hibernate as our DB access. Now we noticed that Hazelcast's default serialization to send event to update the Hibernate 2nd level cache require the full serialization of Hibernate's CacheKey which in our case is particularly large due to embedded keys (3.8Kbytes).

We were wondering if there is a way to send a minimum amount of data across the network and rebuild the CacheKey on the receiving node. In our current implementation we send over the key, entityOrRoleName and tenantId but are having difficulty reconstructing the CacheKey's Type.

Any suggestions on how to do this? Does Hibernate have support to rebuild the CacheKey (of Type) using this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually we use a special Hibernate4CacheKeySerializer. See https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-hibernate/blob/master/hazelcast-hibernate4/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/hibernate/serialization/Hibernate4CacheKeySerializer.java.

This is already more efficient than Java serialisation.

We do not think it is possible to make this more efficient.

Comment: I will approve your answer. At the end of the day we ended up going for a very similar solution. The main difference being that on read, instead of using UNSAFE (I liked this part) I analyzed how Hibernate generates its CacheKey and built something similar. I'm sorry I cannot make my solution available